# ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format when executing a query with a timestamp parameter

Tags: oracle, timestamp, odp.net

I am trying to execute a query on Oracle database table with a TimeStamp(6) column, using odp.net

I am using below code, which throws this exception: "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format".

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr");
using (con)
{
   con.Open();
   OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE LOGDATE > :logDate";
   command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
   command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("logDate", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), ParameterDirection.Input));

   using (command)
   {
      OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader(); //ORA-01840 exception is thrown here
   }
}
```

What is wrong about this query and it's parameters? I also tried OracleDbType.Date, instead of OracleDbType.TimeStamp but i got the same error.

Comment: `Logs` is a table or view? Your code looks fine, do you try to check your query directly in sqldeveloper/sql plus?

Comment: Logs is a table and LOGDATE is a TIMESTAMP(6) column. Query works good when i execute it using TOAD but i think the problem is about the parameter binding.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by passing an OracleTimeStamp object instead of DateTime object. Below code works good:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr");
using (con)
{
   con.Open();
   OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE LOGDATE > :logDate";
   command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
   command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("logDate", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, new OracleTimeStamp(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)), ParameterDirection.Input));

   using (command)
   {
      OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader(); //ORA-01840 exception was thrown here
   }
}
```